# FCM Issue on Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm experiencing a hard time issue. My App uses FCM Push notifications, it was working fine these past years, now when I try to sync it keep on failing, It points many things but all in all it says its unable to resolve either google gsm service or says unable to resolve dependency and it will point to the firebase messaging with whatever version I try.

Heres my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myuser.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
 //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
//implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0"))
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:7.2.0'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:4.3.10'
  //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:32.1.1'
}
```

Here is the current error:

```
 Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[17.0.4].
Open File
Show Details
```

---